# Store a specific numbers of characters from user input in variables #java

Tags: java, string, user-interface, input

I'm developing a Jframe using the GUI designing tool in NetBeans, as part of my school project.

Say the user inputs "ABCDEFG123456" and presses a button. The program should store characters in the range from 2 to 5 of that string in variable1 and from 7 to the end of the string in variable2.

And the result should be:
variable1 = "BCDE"
variable2 = "G123456"

**Update:**

[image]

```
Variables:
1st textarea = ep
rearrange = exe
2nd textarea = output
```

Comment: Can we see some code. Do not be afraid to show us what you have done. :)

Comment: Very willing to help but as gonzo said please add some code :) would feel better and not writing for you! Hint Hint, look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Comment: Use `String#substring`. Good luck.

Comment: I have not written anything, just designed the interface. I just want to know the mechanism to start coding. :)

Comment: @Skylight well lets see your interface. :)

Comment: @gonzo I updated the post.. see the screenshot

Comment: Alright thanks guys, I'm gonna follow your suggestions and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your best bet is [substring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm)

```
       public static void main(String args[]){

          String userInput = new String("ABCDEFG123456");

          String variable1 = userInput.substring(1,5);
          String variable2 = userInput.substring(6, userInput.length());

          System.out.println(variable1);
          System.out.println(variable2);

       }
```

(haven't tested, maybe the indexes are wrong :-) )

Comment: Yes! substring is what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot brother :)